# How to not change other attributes while animating in Maya?

Tags: animation, attributes, maya

I am trying to change the scale and rotation of my object in specific key frames but it changes the object attributes throughout the animation and I do not want that,how do I resolve this problem?
I know its a stupid question but could not figure it out on my own ,so here we go...

Comment: Do you have any code to show?

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about your question, without much information to go by, there could be a few reasons for your unexpected results.

- attributes in question have no keyframe, changing the value is static during the animation and therefore will reflect on the whole time range. If an attribute is not highlighted with a red color in the channel box, then no keyframes exist on that channel.
- your previous and next keyframe could be very far apart and the blend could therefore be creating undesired results. Add keyframes closer to the frame you keyed to have a shorter blend from one value to the other.
- if you are looking for very quick and not blended changes in values, try setting the curves to stepped instead of linear blend. Even there you will have to have at least more than one key to have a change of value during the animation.
- if you are working with animation layers, check whether you you are in additive or overwrite mode. In both cases you might have to create multiple keys.
- in the bottom right of Maya there is a button called "Auto Keyframe". This one will create keyframes automatically when you change values, but will do so only on already keyed channels.
- use the graph editor to see what's going on with your curves for the attributes in question (Windows - Animation - Graph Editor). Don't rely on the red ticks in the main timeline, as you can only see whether a keyframe exists but you can't tell for which attribute(s).